# CDK Unable to Add CodeStarNotification to CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I use CDK to deploy a codepipeline. It works fine until I try to add notification for codepipeline success/fail events. It gives `CREATE_FAILED` error with message `Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: AWS::CodeStarNotifications::NotificationRule" (RequestToken: bb566fd0-1ac9-5d61-03fe-f9c27b4196fa, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)`. What could be the reason? Thanks.

```js
import * as codepipeline from "@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline";
import * as codepipeline_actions from "@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline-actions";
import * as codestar_noti from "@aws-cdk/aws-codestarnotifications";
import * as sns from "@aws-cdk/aws-sns";

    const pipeline = new codepipeline.Pipeline(...);
    const topicArn = props.sns_arn_for_developer;
    const targetTopic = sns.Topic.fromTopicArn(
      this,
      "sns-notification-topic",
      topicArn
    );
    new codestar_noti.NotificationRule(this, "Notification", {
      detailType: codestar_noti.DetailType.BASIC,
      events: [
        "codepipeline-pipeline-pipeline-execution-started",
        "codepipeline-pipeline-pipeline-execution-failed",
        "codepipeline-pipeline-pipeline-execution-succeeded",
        "codepipeline-pipeline-pipeline-execution-canceled",
      ],
      source: pipeline,
      targets: [targetTopic],
    });
```

Here is the snippet of generated cloudformation tempalte.

```
    "Notification2267453E": {
      "Type": "AWS::CodeStarNotifications::NotificationRule",
      "Properties": {
        "DetailType": "BASIC",
        "EventTypeIds": [
          "codepipeline-pipeline-pipeline-execution-started",
          "codepipeline-pipeline-pipeline-execution-failed",
          "codepipeline-pipeline-pipeline-execution-succeeded",
          "codepipeline-pipeline-pipeline-execution-canceled"
        ],
        "Name": "sagemakerbringyourownNotification36194CEC",
        "Resource": {
          "Fn::Join": [
            "",
            [
              "arn:",
              {
                "Ref": "AWS::Partition"
              },
              ":codepipeline:ap-southeast-1:305326993135:",
              {
                "Ref": "sagemakerbringyourownpipeline0A8C43B1"
              }
            ]
          ]
        },
        "Targets": [
          {
            "TargetAddress": "arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-1:305326993135:whitespace_alerts",
            "TargetType": "SNS"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "sagemaker-bring-your-own/Notification/Resource"
      }
    },
```

Comment: Can you confirm the SNS Topic exists?

Comment: @gshpychka, yes, it exists. I have to mannually add permission into the AssessPolicy of the SNS Topic for the notification to work.

Comment: @Qinjie Can you explain what you mean by "add permission into the AssessPolicy of the SNS Topic." What permission do you have to add? And were you unable to add it through CDK?

Comment: @fool4jesus, when you view a SNS topic details, you will see Subscriptions, Access policy, Delivery retry policy etc at the bottom. Click on "Access policy".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because imported resources cannot be modified. As you pointed out in the comments, setting up the notification involves modifying the Topic resource, specifically its access policy.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/resources.html#resources_importing

Answer (score 5):

FWIW, I got the exact same error `"Invalid request provided: AWS::CodeStarNotifications::NotificationRule"` from a CDK app where the `Topic` was  created (not imported). It turned out to be a transient issue, because it succeeded the second time without any changes. I suspect it was due to a very large ECR image which was build the first time as part of the deploy and which took quite some time. My speculation is that the Topic timed out and got into some kind of weird state waiting for the `NotificationRule` to be created.

Comment: Same for me, it succeeded the second time.

Comment: Same here. Deleted stack and ran it again.

Comment: I found this error message in CloudTrail.

"*Creation of this role might take up to 15 minutes. Until it exists, notification rule creation will fail. Wait 15 minutes, and then try again. If this is is not the first time you are creating a notification rule, there might be a problem with a network connection, or one or more AWS services might be experiencing issues*"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by doing the following in that order:

1. First removing the below statement from the resource policy of the SNS topic.
2. Then deploying the stack(which interestingly doesn't add anything to the resource policy)
3. Once the stack deployment finishes, update the resource policy manually to add the below statement.

```
    {
      "Sid": "AWSCodeStarNotifications_publish",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "codestar-notifications.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "SNS:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:ap-south-1:xxxxxxxxx:test"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not fully on topic, but I have experienced the same error message even with the Topic being created in the same stack and this question showed up on google.

The issue in my case was probably a missing dependency: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/29484

Until CDK implements that there is a simple workaround to explicitly add the dependency yourself:

```
const topic = new Topic(...);
const rule = new NotificationRule(..., ..., {
  ...,
  targets: [topic]
});
rule.node.addDependency(topic.node.findChild('Policy'));
```