# Unable to Add CodeStarNotification to CodePipeline with properly configured SNS access policy

Tags: amazon-sns, aws-cdk, aws-codestar

Currently facing an issue about creating a notification rule for code pipeline

```
Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: AWS::CodeStarNotifications::NotificationRule" (RequestToken: 4cf585ed-150e-78ee-6c23-d01870c1dbc4, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

My problem is the same as in this StackOverflow post
[CDK Unable to Add CodeStarNotification to CodePipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71028437/cdk-unable-to-add-codestarnotification-to-codepipeline).

Suggested solutions focus on whether or not access policy on topic is set and this is all taken care in my case

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AWSCodeStarNotifications_publish",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "codestar-notifications.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "SNS:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789:PipelineNotifications"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am importing already existing topic in that stack, that topic already have properly configured access policy so I don’t really understand what’s the problem - tried several times but it never succeeds creating it and it fails.

cdk version 2.31.0

Comment: It would be really helpful to share existing CDK snippet to help us reproduce